# Woocommerce dynamically change price of a variable product once a specific variation is changes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written this to extract the product variation prices

```
global $product;

        if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

            function get_product_variation_price($variation_id) {

                global $woocommerce; 
                $product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
                return $product->get_price_html(); 
                } 
            $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $arr_variations_id = array();
            foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
                $product_variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                $product_price = get_product_variation_price($product_variation_id);
            }

            $amount = get_product_variation_price($product_variation_id);
         
        } else {
            $amount = str_replace(".", ",", $product->get_price());
        }
```

What I am trying to achieve is that if the product is a variable product, the amount variable changes to what currently selected variants set price is, however, this will always get me the first variants price. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean the frontend price inside the product detail page? By default woocommerce already handle price change display when you select a new variation. Are you sure it is not some 3rd party plugin that breaks it?

Comment: Well, yes and no. I'm working on a 3rd party plugin myself that is displaying that `$amount`, I want my plugin to receive the same price, that woocommerce displays when a new variation is changed and rerender, but I can't seem to find a way to get that new price if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to create a plugin for showing variation prices because this is the default from woocommerce. Can you share why are you creating this plugin? Does the default function not work on your site? If you are only looking to change decimals for prices, you can change these settings from currency options.

Comment: I'm aware that there is default function in woocommerce that updates that price and displays chosen variable price. I'm trying to understand how does woocommerce do that, and how can I access that same number. Right now it always displays the lowest price available.